# Is Recursion possible in DB2 PL SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: db2

I am trying to build a recursive Stored Procedure in DB2 PL SQL. But a little late in the game did I realize that it would throw an undefined reference error. So is recursion not possible in DB2 PL SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [IBM Devworks by Serge Rielau and Rick Swagerman](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/recursive_sql_pl?lang=en)

> There are multiple ways in which DB2 supports recursion in SQL. One of
>   which is recursion using the ANSI SQL recursive UNION ALL approach.
>   The other approach is using the CONNECT BY clause.

You need to use Modules or dynamic SQL according to this blog.

Comment: Thank you. I did go through the blog and checked the approach suggested but somehow felt that there would be a more graceful way of doing it. However i have now created 2 different stored procedures with one calling the other is a loop and solved my problem.

Comment: Just to have a record, if recursion has to be somehow achieved at any cost and if it is not possible with a stored procedure, the below link gives an idea of how to achieve it within a SQL query. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000879.html